# Create std::thread from static instance (singelton)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've a few singelton classes, and in the main function I try to run them as thread. But I did not found a solution, to do this.

```cpp
#pragma once

class Game
{
private:
    Game() {}
public:
    static Game& getInstance()
    {
        static Game instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

and I init them like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
        Game game = Gane::getInstance();

        std::thread game_thread(&game.checkStatus, game);
        game_thread.join();

        while (true){}
```

I try to run threads in the main function but it wont work:

```cpp
std::thread game_thread(game.checkStatus);
```

**But I can call the function with the dot syntax only, which is not working for threading.**
I got the following error: **a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function**

If i try it like this, VS Code is not compiling it:

```cpp
std::thread player_thread(&Player::obtainPlayers);
```

and give me following error:
**std::Invoke, No matching overloaded function found**
**Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&…) noexcept()'**

any ideas how to run threads with dotted syntax, since I cant use pointer(->) or static(::) syntax there because of singelton and static return?

I've searched in other topics and nothing worked.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - provide a [mre] including any error messages (or other issues you run into)

Comment: There you go bud, there's your answer.

Comment: @HattedRooster I can't see any working answer. 

Updated my question again

Comment: Use getinstance as second parameter for std::thread

Comment: @HattedRooster like this? `std::thread player_thread(&player.obtainPlayers, Player::getInstance);`
Won't work

Comment: `(&Player::obtainPlayers, Player::getInstance())`